# Visio ShapeSheet manage shape data text using connection points of master

Tags: formula, visio, shapesheet

I am trying to display shape data on a dynamic connector in Visio. This is to display the connection descriptions between classes in a class diagram.

The problem that I face is that visio does not automatically place the data graphics elements (shows in green in the graphic) in a good location when dealing with 2D connection shapes (the placement options are all relative the the shape centre) -- This does not work well with long connectors.

My intention is to use the two connection points at the end points of the connector (shown as CxnLeft and CxnRight) to place the data graphic shape (Text Callout - ID 22 below) in a position that is relative.

I have tried to create a custom parameter (User.LabelPosition3) on the shape data graphic (green shape) so that I can define its x and y co-ordinate however I have not found a way to access the connection shapes Row_1.X property -- As you can see the formula is not working)

I require assistance in any way to access this value. or a technique that would be better to provide this functionality

[image: ShapeSheet Data]

Answer (score 0):

The `Sheet.5` in your formula is incorrect. According to the image that you posted, the correct reference to your connector shape should be `sheet.17`.

In the  **Shape Name** box (near the top of the posted image), the **ID** of the shape is 17. You probably extracted `Sheet.5` from *Master: Association.Sheet.5* which is incorrect.

Therefore to fix your formula, simply type:

`User.LabelPosition3 = Sheet.17!Connections.CxnLeft.X`

But I think the full formula should be:

`User.LabelPosition3 = Sheet.17!Connections.CxnLeft.X + Sheet.17!BeginX`